# how do you send a SOAP request using soapui

Tags: soap, soapui

I have few xml request files for soap. But I am very new in soap. I have also installed soapui. But I don't know how to use 'soapui' to send soap xml request.

Is there any tutorial which will help me to understand entire process of sending soap xml request.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need a wsdl or wadl to start working with soapUI.

To begin with soapUI you can check out http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/getting-started.html and there are several other blogs that you can check out to start learning about soapUI.

Comment: Is there a quick tutorial on how to send a request and save the result as csv? Do I need to create a test case for that? Don't want to read that huge doc.